# How to parse XML file from html5 with javascript in local

Tags: javascript, xml, html, parsexml

I'm trying to parse a XML file with a html file with javascript but not been able don't know why.

When I hit the "Get my cd colection" button it doesn't get any data

Here is my code, cd_catalog.xml

```
<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
    </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

file html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table,th,td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<body>

<h2>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Get my CD collection</button>
<br><br>
<table id="demo"></table>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I open the html file with browser and it doesn't get the data from the xml

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: Failed to load file:///C:/Users/la-60000143/Desktop/PruebaHTML-XML/cd_catalog.xml: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.